# WebAPI Moq Async EF6 UnitTesting

Tags: entity-framework, moq, async-await, entity-framework-6

I'm using Moq to make Mocks for the EF6 Async methods. But something is not working right because i get the following exception:

> The source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncEnumerable{0}. Only
>   sources that implement IDbAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity
>   Framework asynchronous operations. For more details see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=287068.

I have the following code:
UnitTest1.cs

```
    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<MyModel>>();
    mockSet.As<IDbAsyncEnumerable<MyModel>>()
        .Setup(m => m.GetAsyncEnumerator())
        .Returns(new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<MyModel>(data.GetEnumerator()));

    mockSet.As<IQueryable<MyModel>>()
        .Setup(m => m.Provider)
        .Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<MyModel>(data.Provider));

    mockSet.As<IQueryable<MyModel>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<MyModel>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<MyModel>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator()); 

    var mockContext = new Mock<PDBContext>();
    mockContext.Setup(c => c.GetSet<MyModel>()).Returns(mockSet.Object); 

    //Test!
    var controller = new MyModelController();
    controller.MyModelStore = new MyModelStore(mockContext.Object);
    var result = await controller.GetBestOppertunity(2) as OkNegotiatedContentResult<List<MyModel>>;

    //Result
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, result.Content.Count);
```

MyModelStore.cs

```
public async Task<List<MyModel>> GetBestOppertunity(int limit)
{
    return await Context.GetSet<MyModel>().OrderByDescending(x => x.StartDate).Take(limit).ToListAsync();
}
```

I based the code on the following blog to prevent the error from happening: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429

But exactly the error happends that i'm tryging to prevent. The error is explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn313107

The Error happends in the code: GetBestOppertunity(int limit) in MyModelStore.cs.

The GetSet Method showed there is nothing more than a wrapper to be able to attach unit testing to the Set method.

PDBContext.cs (DatabaseFirst)

```
public partial class PDBContext : IPDBContext
{
    public virtual IDbSet<T> GetSet<T>() where T : class
    {
        return Set<T>();
    }
}
```

Any Ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I would implement the unit of work and repository pattern, this would allow you to avoid needing to mock these details at all.  They aren't interesting from a test perspective.

Comment: @Maess In fact i avoided these 2 patterns explicitly, for other reasons in the project.. And i intend to lean more on the MVCS pattern. In this case The Store class that i have made will contain the database logic.
So if i understand your comment well, and applying it to my model. You're saying that i should try to move it off the LINQ query level. And return directly the result before coming to the LINQ layer?

Comment: MVCS and UOW/Repository are not mutual exclusive.  For example your store class could consume IUnitOfWork through DI.